# TypeScript compilation error on windows OS

Tags: node.js, typescript, windows, package.json, tsc

I have created a command in package.json using [tsc-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsc-watch) which is shown below:

```
npx tsc-watch --noClear --compiler ./node_modules/.bin/tsc --onSuccess 'node ./dist/src/index.js'
```

This works perfectly fine on mac but when I run it inside windows it throw below error:

```
\node_modules\.bin\tsc:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Not sure if there is anything wrong with compiler path or anything I am missing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As with many other libraries in the npm ecosystem, it seems that Windows was not properly considered or tested for this library. IMO, only those who enjoy pain and suffering would undertake modern JS/TS development using node/npm in a Windows environment. In Windows, using [WSL2 for a linux desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) or [VSCode remote development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) with linux containers is a much safer way of dealing with a community that often overlooks Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround by not specifying the compiler path and used below command to run it on windows:

```
"npx tsc-watch --noClear --onSuccess \"node ./dist/src/index.js\""
```